# ValueError: zero length field name in format

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert date to a nice format using below code and runninginto following error..can anyone provide inputs on how to overcome here?

```
from datetime import datetime
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1372058963)
print d
create_date = datetime.strptime(str(d), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print create_date
gerrit_created_date = "{}/{}/{}".format(create_date.month,create_date.day,create_date.year)
print gerrit_created_date
```

Error:-

```
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    gerrit_created_date = "{}/{}/{}".format(create_date.month,create_date.day,create_date.year)
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error in python 2.7.5.  I get the output `2013-06-24 03:29:23`, `2013-06-24 03:29:23`, `6/24/2013`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use [`datetime.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
>>> d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1372058963)
>>> datetime.strftime(d, '%m/%d/%Y')
'06/24/2013'
>>> datetime.strftime(d, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
'06/24/2013 12:59:23'
```

Comment: @user2639990 look at the table on the bottom of this page:http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you're using Python 2.6. Specify field numbers.

```
gerrit_created_date = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(create_date.month,create_date.day,create_date.year)
```

---

You can use strftime-style format.

```
gerrit_created_date = "{0:%m/%d/%Y}".format(create_date)
```

To get hour, minute, seconds:

```
gerrit_created_date = "{0:%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S}".format(create_date)
```

Comment: +1  In python 2.6 I can reproduce the error, and @falsetru's suggestion fixes it.